# Python: Multiple entries based on the same group into different columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe products. Products looks this:

```
Cust_ID  Prod   Time_of_Sale
A        Bat      1 
A        Ball     2
A        Lego     3
B        Lego     3
B        Lego     9
B        Ball     11
B        Bat      11
B        Bat      13
C        Bat      2
C        Lego     2
```

I want to change it so that it becomes like this:

```
Cust_ID  Bat   Bat  Ball Lego Lego
A        1     NaN  2    3    NaN
B        11    13   11   3    9  
C        2     NaN  NaN  2    NaN
```

I have been playing around with `products.groupby()` and it is not really leading me anywhere. Any help is appreciated.

The aim is to 'visualize' the order in which each item was purchased by each customer. I have more than 1000 unique Customers.

Edit:
I see that a user suggested that I go through [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe). But this doesn't work because my columns have duplicate values.

Comment: Not exactly. I went through the page to see if it does. A problem with pivot columns is that they are usually unique. If you can see my 2nd table, you see that the columns are not unique. I mean pandas wouldn't allow it, I'll have to rename the duplicates to `bat1`, `bat2` but even then, they are picking up values from `bat` of the original table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little tricky with duplicates on `Prod`. Basically you need a `cumcount` and pivot:

```
new_df = (df.set_index(['Cust_ID','Prod',
                        df.groupby(['Cust_ID', 'Prod']).cumcount()])
     ['Time_of_Sale']
   .unstack(level=(1,2))
   .sort_index(axis=1)
)   
new_df.columns = [x for x,y in new_df.columns]
new_df = new_df.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Cust_ID  Ball   Bat   Bat  Lego  Lego
0       A   2.0   1.0   NaN   3.0   NaN
1       B  11.0  11.0  13.0   3.0   9.0
2       C   NaN   2.0   NaN   2.0   NaN
```

**Note**: Duplicated column names, although supported, should be avoid in Pandas.